# How to maintain display onmouseover after moving mouse with Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have three objectives with these pics, hide all but the first. Display all pics, inline with the first, when hovering over the first and continue display when hovering over all pics. Hide the pics once leaving the area with display only when hover over the first again. (I forgot img sources but they are there in the code) To do this consistently I wrote html, css and js code but I can only achieve two never all three, repeatedly w/o refresh. The code:

```js
var tog = document.querySelector('#toggle');

var glide = document.querySelector('#first')

glide.onmouseover = function() {

  tog.classList.add('picclass');

}

tog.onmouseout = function() {

  tog.classList.remove('picclass');

}
```

```css
.picclass {
  display: flex
}

.pics {
  display: none;
}

.picclass > .pics {
  display: inline-flex;
}

#first {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div id="toggle">

  <img id="first">

  <img class="pics">

  <img class="pics">

</div>
```

Comment: I think I dont realy understand the question, because it's working for me. The three images are inline and only showing if hovering over the first one. But you can do this without js, use in CSS: #first:hover ~ .pics{display: inline-flex} and #toggle {display: flex}

Comment: Right hover if over the first but keep display when mouse moves over the images. Hide when mouse leave area and only display when hover over first again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay now i get it.

Here you have a sample that works. If you want to change the delaying time you have to change it in the setTimeout. (Now its 500milli = 0,5 sec)

https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/ce1ayo93/21/

```
var tog = document.querySelector('#toggle');
var glide = document.querySelector('#first')
var isover = false;

mover = function() {
    isover = true;
  tog.classList.add('picclass');
}

mout = function() {
    isover = false;
    setTimeout(removefunc,500)
}

removefunc =function(){
    if(!isover){
        tog.classList.remove('picclass');
      }
}

glide.onmouseover = mover;
tog.onmouseout = mout;
```

and in the html

```
<img class="pics" src="https://img.fireden.net/v/image/1531/17/1531179205107.png" onmouseover="mover()" onmouseout="mout()">
```

Comment: This is valid. Thanks, trynna figure why mines couldnt do this and yours worked. What happens with the “if (!isover)” code. I get it removes the class but don’t get what you wrote between the if ()

Comment: if the mouse is out, then isover is false and after 500 milli the class is removed, but if in the 500 milli the mouseover function is called, then the class cant be removed, because the isover is set to true